# Exim4 not updating the config.autogenerated file

Tags: exim, exim4

Exim4 has stopped updating the config.autogenerated file after a restart.
It is not failing or throwing any errors. I am restarting it as a service:
`service exim4 restart`. There are no error logs in `/var/log/exim4/` therefore I am not sure why exim4 has suddenly stopped updating.

Are there any additional ways to debug this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It appears there was something exim did not like in my exim4.conf file. As soon as I deleted it, exim was updating correctly on restart.